# Investigating (->) with ghci and trying to get to its roots

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am trying to use ghci to investigate type `(->)`.

I'd love to understand why I can ask `:t (+)`, but not `:t (->)`:

```
Prelude> :t (->)
<interactive>:1:2: error: parse error on input ‘->’
```

Luckily, both operators allow investigation using `:i`, so I presume it's all because `(+)` is a method of class Num, whereas `(->)` is a data.

Diving deeper into `(->)`:

```
Prelude> :i (->)
data (->) (a :: TYPE q) (b :: TYPE r)   -- Defined in ‘GHC.Prim’
infixr 0 ->
instance Applicative ((->) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

But there is no trace of `data (->)` in the [Hackage page for GHC.Prim](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Prim.html). Possibly I am checking the wrong language version, but AFAIS 0.5.3 is the most recent one, and my ghci version is the latest.

**Where can I find the declaration of `data (->)`?**

Eventually, I'd like to read about `TYPE`, but all the pages I retrieve on Google are talking of `type`.

**Where can I find information about `TYPE`?**

Comment: `(->)` is a type constructor. You can investigate it with `:k (->)`

Comment: Thank you! Can you also shed some light on the GHC.Prim mistery?

Comment: `GCH.Prim` are the primitive types.

Comment: I know, but then why `:info` says that `data (->)` is defined in GHC.Prim ? Where is `data (->)` actually defined?

Comment: I believe the answer is, _it isn't_ really defined. In older Haskell versions, it wouldn't even have been possible. It's really just a compiler build-in.

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli: it is defined in the compiler. The module does not really exists.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you. Can I assume the same for `TYPE` ?

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli To expand on WillemVanOnsem’s statement, `GHC.Prim` contains [a whole lot of definitions for primitive types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/src/GHC.Prim.html), but just defines them as [\_|\_](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom), and leaves the actual definitions to the compiler itself.

Comment: @bradrn - thank you for mentioning `_|_`. On the other hand, `(->)` (or many other variations I tried on that) is not mentioned in the page you linked. So the info provided by `:info (->)` seems to be [not entirely accurate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEbwZfkeIt8)...

Comment: Unless you are dealing with advanced stuff, you can pretend that `(->) :: * -> * -> *`, so `(->)` takes two types and returns a type. More in depth: `*` is just another name for `Type`, or the lower level `TYPE 'LiftedRep`. In the general case `(->)` is "polykinded" as if it were something like `(->) :: forall rep. TYPE rep -> TYPE rep -> *` which allows specializations like `(->) :: TYPE 'UnliftedRep -> TYPE 'UnliftedRep -> *` which are used on unlifted types e.g.  `(Int# -> Int#) :: *`. This is used to enable the low-level optimizations involving unlifted primitive values/tuples/sums.

Comment: `GHC.Prim` has no source code anywhere. It's completely generated by the compiler. The bogus definitions you'll see if you look at the source link in the Haddock documentation exist only in that documentation. Some things that are assigned a "home module" of `GHC.Prim` don't even appear in its documentation because it's too inconvenient to make that happen. General rule: `GHC.Prim` is a lie that exists for the convenience of compiler implementers. With rare temporary exceptions, you shouldn't use it and don't need to bother looking at it.

Comment: When GHCi tells you something is defined there, read that as "from the sky".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since answers have been given in the comments, I sum them up here:

- `(->)` is a type constructor. You can investigate it with `:k (->)` [@Willem van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem)
- `GHC.Prim` has no source code anywhere. It is completely generated by the compiler and you don't need to bother looking at it. When GHCi tells you something is defined there, read that as saying it comes "from the sky" [@dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer)